# insert into picture content control with Open XML

Tags: openxml-sdk

How do I insert a picture (located somewhere on my HDD) in a Picture Content Control using Open XML SDK? This should be an easy task, but surprisingly I couldn't find any examples or answers on the web.

Any help would be welcomed.

Thank you,

Victor

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and same frustration at the lack of examples, but was able to find something that worked for me.  Basically, I stream an image into a `byte[]`, save that stream as a `.png`, and take that `byte[].ToArray()` in a `XMLWriter.WriteBase64` element that is bound to an image content control.

```
var pic = Image.FromFile(server.MapPath(@"images/someImage.png"));
var picStream = new MemoryStream {Position = 0};
pic.Save(picStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
var picBytes = picStream.ToArray();

writer.WriteStartElement("RiskScoreImage");
writer.WriteBase64(picBytes, 0, picBytes.Length);
writer.WriteEndElement();

picStream.Flush();
picStream.Close();
pic.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this:
http://ericwhite.com/blog/2011/03/27/replacing-a-picture-in-a-picture-content-control-in-an-open-xml-wordprocessingml-document/

Answer (score -1):

Although I can't give you a definitive answer (I haven't done anything with openXML for about a year), I'd suggest having a browse through the source code of the DocX project on codeplex.  From what I remember they have support for pictures.